# Split string into more than 9 columns using sed

Tags: shell, sed

I split a string in a input file as:

```
sed -r 's/(.{14})(.{1})(.{8})(.{1})(.{8})(.{1})(.{8})(.{1})(.{8})(.{1})(.{8})(.{1})(.{8})(.*)/\1 \2 \3 \4 \5 \6 \7 \8 \9 \10 \11 \12 \13 \14/' input
```

Input file content:

```
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
5555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555
3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
1111112222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
2222225555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555
```

Output:

```
11111111111111 1 11111111 1 11111111 1 11111111 1 11111111 111111111111110 111111111111111 111111111111112 111111111111113 111111111111114
22222222222222 2 22222222 2 22222222 2 22222222 2 22222222 222222222222220 222222222222221 222222222222222 222222222222223 222222222222224
55555555555555 5 55555555 5 55555555 5 55555555 5 55555555 555555555555550 555555555555551 555555555555552 555555555555553 555555555555554
33333333333333 3 33333333 3 33333333 3 33333333 3 33333333 333333333333330 333333333333331 333333333333332 333333333333333 333333333333334
11111122222222 2 22222222 2 22222222 2 22222222 2 22222222 111111222222220 111111222222221 111111222222222 111111222222223 111111222222224
22222255555555 5 55555555 5 55555555 5 55555555 5 55555555 222222555555550 222222555555551 222222555555552 222222555555553 222222555555554
```

Why the column started from 10 cannot be split properly?

How to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Because sed only supports from `\1` to `\9` as back-references.

Comment: not clear what you mean here. What should be the output? where are lines starting with 10? what is your ultimate goal here?

Comment: @EtanReisner Do you have any idea of doing this splitting please?

Comment: Use `awk` and `FIELDWIDTHS`? Use `cut`?

Comment: if sed is mandatory, use several `s/\(\)/\/` with max 9 group that you can reference in each action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Etan suggests, just use GNU awk with FIELDWIDTHS:

```
$ awk -v FIELDWIDTHS="14 1 8 1 8 1 8 1 8 1 8 1 8" '{$1=$1}1' file
11111111111111 1 11111111 1 11111111 1 11111111 1 11111111 1 11111111 1 11111111
22222222222222 2 22222222 2 22222222 2 22222222 2 22222222 2 22222222 2 22222222
55555555555555 5 55555555 5 55555555 5 55555555 5 55555555 5 55555555 5 55555555
33333333333333 3 33333333 3 33333333 3 33333333 3 33333333 3 33333333 3 33333333
11111122222222 2 22222222 2 22222222 2 22222222 2 22222222 2 22222222 2 22222222
22222255555555 5 55555555 5 55555555 5 55555555 5 55555555 5 55555555 5 55555555
```